# Sorting multiple rows as a single column using Python.

Tags: python

As you can see from the .txt file below, what I intend to achieve is:
For each identifier, i.e 29,30, 31 and so on, I want to take all the rows for each identifier and put them in a single column. It would be nice to remove the 'K1' as well. So basically at the end, there will 9 columns with many rows of data. I would have loved to solve it myself but I am totally short of time to trial and error. It would be great if you guys can help me out.

```
             -29-       K1:      4.2735E+05      4.3904E+05      4.5718E+05      4.8817E+05      5.4312E+05
                        K1:      7.3055E+05      1.1069E+06      1.6420E+06      2.4611E+06      3.4179E+06
                        K1:      4.4951E+06      5.6975E+06      6.9872E+06      8.3390E+06      9.7442E+06
                        K1:      1.1191E+07      1.2660E+07      1.4145E+07      1.5650E+07      1.7172E+07
                        K1:      1.8700E+07      2.0219E+07      2.1725E+07      2.3218E+07      2.4696E+07
                        K1:      2.6156E+07      2.7587E+07      2.8989E+07      3.0361E+07      3.1718E+07
                        K1:      3.3164E+07      3.4862E+07
             -30-       K1:      9.2186E+05      9.2199E+05      9.2134E+05      9.2164E+05      9.2075E+05
                        K1:      9.1836E+05      9.1954E+05      9.1928E+05      3.0813E+06      3.9755E+06
                        K1:      2.3131E+06      2.5546E+06      2.7332E+06      2.8727E+06      2.9952E+06
                        K1:      3.0875E+06      3.1166E+06      3.1092E+06      3.0592E+06      2.9703E+06
                        K1:      2.8246E+06      2.6487E+06      2.4648E+06      2.2807E+06      2.0752E+06
                        K1:      1.7324E+06      1.3371E+06      8.6208E+05      3.1255E+05      4.3936E+04
                        K1:     -3.2260E+05     -6.0556E+05
             -31-       K1:      9.4197E+05      9.4200E+05      9.4127E+05      9.4106E+05      9.4132E+05
                        K1:      9.4327E+05      9.4194E+05      9.4225E+05      3.0970E+06      3.9942E+06
                        K1:      4.8227E+06      5.5341E+06      6.1198E+06      6.6016E+06      7.0045E+06
                        K1:      7.3187E+06      7.5190E+06      7.6389E+06      7.6793E+06      7.6466E+06
                        K1:      7.5266E+06      7.3461E+06      7.1328E+06      6.8899E+06      6.6004E+06
                        K1:      6.2507E+06      5.8471E+06      5.3625E+06      4.8011E+06      4.1676E+06
                        K1:      3.4331E+06      2.9632E+06
             -32-       K1:      9.4089E+05      9.4070E+05      9.4016E+05      9.4026E+05      9.4015E+05
                        K1:      9.3932E+05      9.3955E+05      9.3942E+05      3.0909E+06      4.0011E+06
                        K1:      2.3339E+06      2.5748E+06      2.7522E+06      2.8903E+06      3.0113E+06
                        K1:      3.1016E+06      3.1288E+06      3.1199E+06      3.0689E+06      2.9790E+06
                        K1:      2.8324E+06      2.6560E+06      2.4711E+06      2.2859E+06      2.0793E+06
                        K1:      1.7387E+06      1.3434E+06      8.6692E+05      3.1210E+05      4.0843E+04
                        K1:     -3.2145E+05     -6.2328E+05
             -33-       K1:      9.4889E+05      9.4904E+05      9.4849E+05      9.4857E+05      9.4842E+05
                        K1:      9.4797E+05      9.4799E+05      9.4809E+05      3.0905E+06      4.0104E+06
                        K1:      4.8430E+06      5.5598E+06      6.1519E+06      6.6411E+06      7.0524E+06
                        K1:      7.3755E+06      7.5859E+06      7.7166E+06      7.7689E+06      7.7489E+06
                        K1:      7.6431E+06      7.4778E+06      7.2790E+06      7.0506E+06      6.7754E+06
                        K1:      6.4401E+06      6.0493E+06      5.5774E+06      5.0257E+06      4.3994E+06
                        K1:      3.6721E+06      3.1921E+06
             -34-       K1:      9.5109E+05      9.5097E+05      9.5042E+05      9.5052E+05      9.5047E+05
                        K1:      9.4989E+05      9.5001E+05      9.4991E+05      3.0875E+06      4.0237E+06
                        K1:      2.3439E+06      2.5840E+06      2.7604E+06      2.8977E+06      3.0186E+06
                        K1:      3.1094E+06      3.1385E+06      3.1320E+06      3.0848E+06      3.0000E+06
                        K1:      2.8600E+06      2.6914E+06      2.5138E+06      2.3357E+06      2.1366E+06
                        K1:      1.8181E+06      1.4438E+06      9.8956E+05      4.5490E+05      1.9655E+05
                        K1:     -1.5399E+05     -4.5865E+05
             -35-       K1:      9.6455E+05      9.6459E+05      9.6377E+05      9.6384E+05      9.6355E+05
                        K1:      9.6521E+05      9.6406E+05      9.6479E+05      3.0927E+06      4.0407E+06
                        K1:      4.8796E+06      5.6050E+06      6.2076E+06      6.7089E+06      7.1343E+06
                        K1:      7.4727E+06      7.7009E+06      7.8500E+06      7.9231E+06      7.9256E+06
                        K1:      7.8451E+06      7.7070E+06      7.5352E+06      7.3340E+06      7.0864E+06
                        K1:      6.7807E+06      6.4190E+06      5.9785E+06      5.4571E+06      4.8602E+06
                        K1:      4.1565E+06      3.6840E+06
             -36-       K1:      9.4382E+05      9.4314E+05      9.4290E+05      9.4317E+05      9.4365E+05
                        K1:      9.4070E+05      9.4213E+05      9.4145E+05      3.0611E+06      4.0363E+06
                        K1:      2.3368E+06      2.5769E+06      2.7535E+06      2.8914E+06      3.0145E+06
                        K1:      3.1088E+06      3.1442E+06      3.1438E+06      3.1050E+06      3.0301E+06
                        K1:      2.9032E+06      2.7489E+06      2.5853E+06      2.4205E+06      2.2355E+06
                        K1:      1.9550E+06      1.6183E+06      1.2061E+06      7.1347E+05      4.8245E+05
                        K1:      1.5065E+05     -1.4123E+05
             -37-       K1:     -4.8051E+06     -2.1630E+07     -8.8415E+07     -2.3794E+08     -5.2223E+08
                        K1:     -1.7084E+09     -4.2516E+09     -8.0371E+09     -1.4024E+10     -2.1404E+10
                        K1:     -3.0006E+10     -3.9706E+10     -5.0364E+10     -6.1872E+10     -7.4177E+10
                        K1:     -8.7199E+10     -1.0083E+11     -1.1505E+11     -1.2990E+11     -1.4541E+11
                        K1:     -1.6152E+11     -1.7815E+11     -1.9528E+11     -2.1295E+11     -2.3114E+11
                        K1:     -2.4986E+11     -2.6904E+11     -2.8870E+11     -3.0891E+11     -3.2966E+11
                        K1:     -3.5090E+11     -3.7072E+11
```

Comment: So do you want 1 col or 9? It isn't clear.

Comment: Post an example output as well

Comment: @Coldspeed . I want 9 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import csv

with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = []
    for line in f:
        items = re.split('[\s]+', line.strip())
        if not line.strip().startswith('K1'):
            data.append([])
            data[-1].extend([items[0]] + items[2:])

        else:
            data[-1].extend(items[1:])

data = list(map(list, zip(*data)))

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:   
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

---

And your csv data looks like this:

```
-29-,-30-,-31-,-32-,-33-,-34-,-35-,-36-,-37-
4.2735E+05,9.2186E+05,9.4197E+05,9.4089E+05,9.4889E+05,9.5109E+05,9.6455E+05,9.4382E+05,-4.8051E+06
4.3904E+05,9.2199E+05,9.4200E+05,9.4070E+05,9.4904E+05,9.5097E+05,9.6459E+05,9.4314E+05,-2.1630E+07
4.5718E+05,9.2134E+05,9.4127E+05,9.4016E+05,9.4849E+05,9.5042E+05,9.6377E+05,9.4290E+05,-8.8415E+07
4.8817E+05,9.2164E+05,9.4106E+05,9.4026E+05,9.4857E+05,9.5052E+05,9.6384E+05,9.4317E+05,-2.3794E+08
5.4312E+05,9.2075E+05,9.4132E+05,9.4015E+05,9.4842E+05,9.5047E+05,9.6355E+05,9.4365E+05,-5.2223E+08
7.3055E+05,9.1836E+05,9.4327E+05,9.3932E+05,9.4797E+05,9.4989E+05,9.6521E+05,9.4070E+05,-1.7084E+09
1.1069E+06,9.1954E+05,9.4194E+05,9.3955E+05,9.4799E+05,9.5001E+05,9.6406E+05,9.4213E+05,-4.2516E+09
1.6420E+06,9.1928E+05,9.4225E+05,9.3942E+05,9.4809E+05,9.4991E+05,9.6479E+05,9.4145E+05,-8.0371E+09
2.4611E+06,3.0813E+06,3.0970E+06,3.0909E+06,3.0905E+06,3.0875E+06,3.0927E+06,3.0611E+06,-1.4024E+10
3.4179E+06,3.9755E+06,3.9942E+06,4.0011E+06,4.0104E+06,4.0237E+06,4.0407E+06,4.0363E+06,-2.1404E+10
4.4951E+06,2.3131E+06,4.8227E+06,2.3339E+06,4.8430E+06,2.3439E+06,4.8796E+06,2.3368E+06,-3.0006E+10
5.6975E+06,2.5546E+06,5.5341E+06,2.5748E+06,5.5598E+06,2.5840E+06,5.6050E+06,2.5769E+06,-3.9706E+10
6.9872E+06,2.7332E+06,6.1198E+06,2.7522E+06,6.1519E+06,2.7604E+06,6.2076E+06,2.7535E+06,-5.0364E+10
8.3390E+06,2.8727E+06,6.6016E+06,2.8903E+06,6.6411E+06,2.8977E+06,6.7089E+06,2.8914E+06,-6.1872E+10
9.7442E+06,2.9952E+06,7.0045E+06,3.0113E+06,7.0524E+06,3.0186E+06,7.1343E+06,3.0145E+06,-7.4177E+10
1.1191E+07,3.0875E+06,7.3187E+06,3.1016E+06,7.3755E+06,3.1094E+06,7.4727E+06,3.1088E+06,-8.7199E+10
1.2660E+07,3.1166E+06,7.5190E+06,3.1288E+06,7.5859E+06,3.1385E+06,7.7009E+06,3.1442E+06,-1.0083E+11
1.4145E+07,3.1092E+06,7.6389E+06,3.1199E+06,7.7166E+06,3.1320E+06,7.8500E+06,3.1438E+06,-1.1505E+11
1.5650E+07,3.0592E+06,7.6793E+06,3.0689E+06,7.7689E+06,3.0848E+06,7.9231E+06,3.1050E+06,-1.2990E+11
1.7172E+07,2.9703E+06,7.6466E+06,2.9790E+06,7.7489E+06,3.0000E+06,7.9256E+06,3.0301E+06,-1.4541E+11
1.8700E+07,2.8246E+06,7.5266E+06,2.8324E+06,7.6431E+06,2.8600E+06,7.8451E+06,2.9032E+06,-1.6152E+11
2.0219E+07,2.6487E+06,7.3461E+06,2.6560E+06,7.4778E+06,2.6914E+06,7.7070E+06,2.7489E+06,-1.7815E+11
2.1725E+07,2.4648E+06,7.1328E+06,2.4711E+06,7.2790E+06,2.5138E+06,7.5352E+06,2.5853E+06,-1.9528E+11
2.3218E+07,2.2807E+06,6.8899E+06,2.2859E+06,7.0506E+06,2.3357E+06,7.3340E+06,2.4205E+06,-2.1295E+11
2.4696E+07,2.0752E+06,6.6004E+06,2.0793E+06,6.7754E+06,2.1366E+06,7.0864E+06,2.2355E+06,-2.3114E+11
2.6156E+07,1.7324E+06,6.2507E+06,1.7387E+06,6.4401E+06,1.8181E+06,6.7807E+06,1.9550E+06,-2.4986E+11
2.7587E+07,1.3371E+06,5.8471E+06,1.3434E+06,6.0493E+06,1.4438E+06,6.4190E+06,1.6183E+06,-2.6904E+11
2.8989E+07,8.6208E+05,5.3625E+06,8.6692E+05,5.5774E+06,9.8956E+05,5.9785E+06,1.2061E+06,-2.8870E+11
3.0361E+07,3.1255E+05,4.8011E+06,3.1210E+05,5.0257E+06,4.5490E+05,5.4571E+06,7.1347E+05,-3.0891E+11
3.1718E+07,4.3936E+04,4.1676E+06,4.0843E+04,4.3994E+06,1.9655E+05,4.8602E+06,4.8245E+05,-3.2966E+11
3.3164E+07,-3.2260E+05,3.4331E+06,-3.2145E+05,3.6721E+06,-1.5399E+05,4.1565E+06,1.5065E+05,-3.5090E+11
3.4862E+07,-6.0556E+05,2.9632E+06,-6.2328E+05,3.1921E+06,-4.5865E+05,3.6840E+06,-1.4123E+05,-3.7072E+11
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much.